# iPad - window.open("tel:555", "_top") is not invoking default behavior

Tags: javascript, ipad, call, invoke, window.open

I'm developing an mobile site and need to invoke a phone call on mobile at the `touchend` event. On iPhone and Android the `window.open('tel:555', '_top')` is working fine, invoking a phone call.

On iPad, the default behavior is to offer a "Add to contacts" or "Copy" option. When using a link, it's working fine, as in `<a href='tel:555'>555</a>`

When trying `window.open('tel:555', '_top')` on iPad I'm getting:

> Cannot Open Page
>
> Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid.

I've also tried `setTimeout('window.location="tel:555";', 500);` from [How to trigger click-to-call with javascript (iphone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237694/how-to-trigger-click-to-call-with-javascript-iphone), same problem.

**Is there a way to invoke the default behavior with Javascript?**

Comment: This might help you - it did me

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930001/force-link-to-open-in-mobile-safari-from-a-web-app-with-javascript

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the correct behaviour.

In the [Apple URL Scheme Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html) they specifically say that...

*If the Phone application is not installed on the device, opening a tel URL displays an appropriate warning message to the user.*

I would assume that an iPod Touch would also produce a similar error.

Comment: Hi, Robert. If you tap a <a href="tel:555"> on an iPad, it will prompt you to "Add to Contacts". I just want to do it with Javascript, instead of user touch.